# PHP File Upload Write Disk Error

Tags: php, file, upload, disk

Suddenly, I cannot upload files through a web form using my GoDaddy hosting account.  Here is a basic form located at http://www.fordcorepro.com/upload.php:

```
<form action="upload_submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <label for="fileField"></label>
  <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It simply posts a file to upload_submit.php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Any file that I attempt to upload, no matter the type or size, will NOT write to disk for processing:

> Array ( [fileField] => Array ( [name] => Whining.txt [type] =>
>   [tmp_name] => [error] => 7 [size] => 0 ) )

I get error code 7, or disk write error.  GoDaddy says there is nothing on their end causing this, and that it's something in my SCRIPT.  I told them there might be writing permissions, which they denied.  Any ideas?  The file I'm attempting to upload is only 13KB.

Comment: /tmp could be sized constrained

Answer (score 0):

I had this happening to me... I had filled the disk (actually the partition for the temporary file uploads) :-( .

Comment: GoDaddy states that there are no storage restrictions that could be causing this error.  I'm well below all storage limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded a 11KB text file at the URL you gave and it uploaded file (the array showed error =0 and correct filesize)

What type of file are you uploading, and what does the upload array tell you?

The upload array told me:

`Array ( [fileField] => Array ( [name] => New Text Document.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpCBroC6 [error] => 0 [size] => 12161 ) )`

Comment: In the example above, Whining.txt is a 1KB text file.  It is generating an array printout of Array ( [fileField] => Array ( [name] => Whining.txt [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 7 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Ok, since it is definitely working at my end, I do not really think this is a godaddy or code issue. What does whining.txt contain? Can you create a new txt file add just a few simple lines, upload the new file and check? Make sure it has enough content to be some 10Kb or so in size..

Comment: I created a text file named text.txt, containing only the sentence "This is a test".  Upload results in the array prinout: Array ( [fileField] => Array ( [name] => test.txt [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 7 [size] => 0 ) ) - I tried this in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Create a file with same name and content and uploaded using Chrome: got uploaded correctly. `Array ( [fileField] => Array ( [name] => test.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpgc02Lr [error] => 0 [size] => 14 ))`

Comment: So it's isolated to my system - either my computer or my network.  I'll try to test that theory out and let you know how it works.

Comment: Maybe your firewall is blocking uploads or something?

Answer (score 0):

This could simply be an issue with the /tmp folder on the server: sometimes there's a special partition for it, and that partition simply ran out of space.

You can change the `php_tmp_dir` setting in php.ini.  Read mroe about it [in PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir).